# get rid of stretched faces on models?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

Here is the scenario, for a project i'm working on i need to stretch a uv sphere into a long spike and then apply a displacement on it (let's for convenience sake say i'm using the procedural voronoi displacement found in blender), the problem is when i stretch it the faces get all stretched out and the displacement just looks like streaks, is there any way i could stretch out a uv sphere into a long spike, and then change the faces back into a similar arrangement as the non stretched out uv sphere? i have tried the remesh option but the displacement still just looks like streaks. i am using the latest release of blender.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say enough about your final purpose, for example is it supposed to be animated, is the texture supposed to be exactly the same or about the same, etc?

If you're animating it with shape keys you could use the *Texture Coordinate's Object* output socket. The texture won't deform:

[image]
[image]